# "node" which can hold different values to be read by a sensor?

Tags: sensor, passive-components

I have a question about sensors which are able to read values of specific "nodes".
The "nodes" in my context are like little metallic materials which can be placed somewhere i.e. within a flat wooden tile and have **NO** electrical connection.
A sensor should then be able to read values from them.

**edited: more detailed example:** (asked for by @andresgongora )

You have two items here. One is a small wooden board with 2x2 painted marks - just like a chess game with four fields. Then you have a stick to point onto those fields. When touching such a field you should be able to receive a message on your App on the smartphone.

### The actual idea I'm not happy with:

> Sensors on each of the
>   fields and actually an electrical component -> a microcontroller like
>   an ESP8266 which reads the change of current on those sensors as they
>   are being touched by some metallic device (the stick). Then the
>   ESP8266 would deliver information to the App through WiFi.

### The alternative way I'd like to do it:

> The former sensors on every field are now detached elements on the
>   fields. They are not read by an microcontroller to receive any
>   information about their changing state but are more likely able to
>   hold a fixed state which might be predefined anyhow. The "stick" in
>   this case is the "reader" in this case. It hovers/touches a field and
>   can determine the difference by those fields. That way the stick has
>   to be connected to the app to deliver this information. Most
>   importently is that the fields hold predefined values in any case.
>   This state should not be volatile and should last around 30 years.

Those nodes should be "progammed" to that value anyhow.

Sorry guys I know this is a weird question - but since so many fantastic things are possible thanks to microcontrollers and electrical components I kinda do not feel that stupid with this questions :D

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: As the title says. I need a component to substitute the placeholder word "node" to something that gives the functionality in the questions detail

Comment: 2D barcodes read with a camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes into my mind with what you have said is RFID. Your "nodes" would be passive tags which get powered up when the reader gets close (thanks to wireless power transmition). Then your node answers to the reader sending an ID.

You say your "nodes" are electrically passive, but want them to be able to transmit complex and programmable information. So another option would be using small button-baterry powered microcontrollers which could last [several years on a single battery charge](https://www.google.es/url?q=http://www.ti.com/tool/tida-00756&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiH8dLfy7rPAhXCmBoKHbctC-4QFggPMAI&sig2=OXIV09CuCmo6ppdFJlf9hw&usg=AFQjCNGX0Y-JO1pN1EmfaPaSG_yLx7SwdQ). You could even take it a step further and use one of the many sorts of energy harvesting technologies to remove the battery all together.

Could you please elaborate your requieremnts? We will try to provide you with the best answer once we know your specific requirements :)

---

**EDIT 02-10-2016**

Let me see if I got it right ;)

> You have an array of "smart" sensors, each of which is consist of the
>   actual sensor and some smart electronics that can be programmed to
>   inform about the sensor output and of its unique ID (and maybe other
>   variable/programable data).
>
> These sensors are laid out in front of the user, which accesses them
>   with a reader. In case of RFID it could be the actual RFID reader, but
>   becaouse they are so close together and you want to avoid
>   interferences, you prefer a conductive stick.
>
> When the user touches one of the sensors with the stick, you want the
>   sensor to send it's data through that stick to an end device. This
>   end-device could be your smartphone, and the stick is connected to it
>   through the USB port.

Some more daditional info would help me a lot here to decide which approach to take. But if a client of mine really wanted such a setup I would encourage him to reconsider.

If you want to send data over a conductive stick, this data has to be sent preferably using a single wire serial port, like RS-232 (UART).

Which is actually possible. Once you make electrical contact, you can receive data. Nevertheless, small bounces (while making contact) would make this circuit unreliable.

I would do something different, with a similar end result:

> Have all smart-sensors carry a small button on top. Then interconnect
>   them using an appropriate communications bus, like I²C in multi-master
>   mode. Finally, ad to your multi-node system a node with Bluetooth
>   which connects to your smart-phone.
>
> Once a smart-sensor detects you have pressed its button, its sends to
>   the Bluetooth node all information you want, which you can then
>   receive on your smart-phone.

I hope you find this useful, but your question is really complicated and I would need more details. For example, why don't you upload a simple pseudo-schematic of what your want, or a small flow diagram :)

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I did not received any update on your answer. Well actually you really understood what I want to achieve. I now understand the issue to the first approach. As you said with the I²C multi-master - great idea! What might be not that good is the button thingie. In fact the user should only "touch" not "press" the plates. Almost hovering. What I thought about is something like components which will change its "resistance" value as I touch them, either by stick or hand. A µC then would locate the node with the resi-difference by PIN number or something else.

Comment: btw I found an article about those "tip toy" pencils. I hope that article is in english for you. Actually how this works is that the fields are fine grain printed with different dot-patterns. The infraret reader is capable of reading those. This really looks like a nice low-tech approach https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiptoi

Comment: @xetra I'm glad you found this approach useful. Do not hesitate to post follow-up questions if you need them. We here at EE.SE will be glad to help you :)